# How do I secure a public API that requires no authentication?

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, api-key

I made a web api that does that follow services:

1. Returns the list of current job openings of the company (GET)
2. Apply on any job that is currently opened (POST).

The API is then consumed by an angularJS front end. Most of the authentications that I found from the web requires login but our website doesn't so I can't really use token bearer.

What are the list of things that I must implement or consider? are there any threats and how do I get around them?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably add a ClientId/ClientSecret to your SPA and somehow securely send it as part of every request probably a AngularJs interceptor will help.

On the webAPI side accept only those requests that have a valid clientId, do that probably using a filter.

A similar infrastructure is explained here http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/ (clientId,ClientSecret part)

Hope this helps.